# Trigger to prevent deletion of account if account has atleast one contact associated with it using trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger, trigger

Below is my code but dont know how to validate it exactly in code.new to code

```
trigger AccountContactCheck on Account (before delete) {
Set<id> accountids=new set<id>();
for(account acc:trigger.old){
    accountids.add(acc.id);
}Map<id,contact>conmap=new map<id,contact>([select accountid from contact where accountid in :accountids]);
System.debug('conmap>>>>'+conmap.keySet());
for(account acc:trigger.old){
    if(conmap.get(acc.id)!=null){
        System.debug('Inside If of account >>>>>>');
        acc.adderror('Contact is associated with it.you cant delete account');

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Aditi, are you wondering whether this code will work?  I'm curious what you mean by validate other than trying to delete a Contact from an Account.

Comment: Yes if account is having any contact then i need to prevent account from deletion.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have did mistake while capture **conmap** Map, In **conmap** your storing **key id** as **contact id** and value as **accountid**.

```
if(conmap.get(acc.id)!=null)
```

In the above code your match **account id** with **contact id** , ie.. the reason **if** **condition** always be **false** in your case, your not able go inside **if** **condition**.

Try below code it will work for you.

**You can use group by clause make shorten in code**

```
trigger AccountContactCheck on Account (before delete) {   
for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT accountid, count(id)size  FROM contact where accountid in : Trigger.oldMap.keySet() GROUP BY accountid])
    if(((integer)ar.get('size'))>0)
         trigger.oldMap.get((id)ar.get('accountid')).adderror('******* Contact is associated with it.you cant delete account');         
}
```

#### OR

**Alternate**

```
 trigger AccountContactCheck on Account (before delete) { 
        List<contact> Contacts = [select accountid from contact where accountid in : Trigger.oldMap.keySet()];
        set<id> accIds=new set<id>();
          for(contact con: Contacts)
                 accIds.add(con.accountid);

        for(account acc:trigger.old)
            if(accIds.contains(acc.id))
                acc.adderror('******* Contact is associated with it.you cant delete account');            
    }
```

Comment: Nitesh.if you have some sample example of trigger with scenarios .can you please provide me.as i am new to sfdc and want to learn triggers

Comment: Your welcome......

Comment: @Aditi  What exactly you wanted ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm

Comment: I know the basic .but i am getting stuck when some complex kind of logic i need to build.so i need some scenarios with the triggers where i can actually get the understanding how to build logic .I need some Examples like above which i done.my email Id aditi.n.mishra@gmail.com

Comment: Your are on right platform, Already stack exchange has lot of question on trigger, follow the question on trigger try to answer your own,  then check with answer present.

Comment: Your question already tag with trigger, Click on trigger you get all the question related to trigger.  Stack exchange people always ready to help when your struck.